# Error when running composer install An error occurred when executing the \"'cache:clear --no-warmup'\" command:

Tags: php, symfony, vagrant, ansible, composer-php

I am trying to boot up a Vagrant machine(with ansible) that is throwing an error when it gets to the task of "composer install".  I searched this problem and tried multiple solutions that did not work(explained below).

I believe it has to do with vagrant user not having permission to write to app/cache and app/log even if I change the permission on VM and local.  Not sure what the fix would be.

Error:

> failed: [default] (item=composer install) => {"changed": true, "cmd":
>   ["composer", "install"], "delta": "0:00:06.144861", "end": "2017-11-16
>   12:03:03.366269", "failed": true, "item": "composer install", "rc": 1,
>   "start": "2017-11-16 12:02:57.221408", "stderr": "Loading composer
>   repositories with package information\nInstalling dependencies
>   (including require-dev) from lock file\nNothing to install or
>   update\nGenerating autoload files\n>
>   Incenteev\ParameterHandler\ScriptHandler::buildParameters\n>
>   Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap\n>
>   Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache\nScript
>   Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache
>   handling the symfony-scripts event terminated with an exception\n\n
>   \n  [RuntimeException]
>   \n  An error occurred when executing the \"'cache:clear --no-warmup'\"
>   command:
>   \n   // Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug true
>   \n
>   \n    [Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException]
>   \n    Failed to remove directory
>   \"/var/www/fisher.dev/app/cache/de~/annotations\": .
>   \n
>   \n  cache:clear [--no-warmup] [--no-optional-warmers] [-h|--help]
>   [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi]
>   [-n|--no-interaction] [-s|--shell] [--process-isolation] [-e|--env
>   ENV] [--no-debug] [--]   \n  .
>   \n

Composer.json file:

```
{
"name": "fostermadeco/fisher",
"license": "proprietary",
"type": "project",
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "app/AppKernel.php",
        "app/AppCache.php"
    ]
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.11.3",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "snc/redis-bundle": "^2.0",
    "predis/predis": "^1.1",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "1.2.1",
    "alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter": "^1.0",
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "^1.2",
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "^3.2",
    "ocramius/package-versions": "^1.1",
    "ircmaxell/random-lib": "^1.2",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "^1.1",
    "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "^2.13",
    "maba/webpack-bundle": "^0.6.4",
    "stripe/stripe-php": "^4.3",
    "doctrine/annotations": "^1.3",
    "bugsnag/bugsnag-symfony": "^1.0",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "^1.2",
    "danielstjules/stringy": "^2.3",
    "doctrine/migrations": "1.4.1",
    "beberlei/DoctrineExtensions": "1.0.*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~3.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "~2.7",
    "doctrine/data-fixtures": "^1.2",
    "hautelook/alice-bundle": "^1.4"
},
"scripts": {
    "symfony-scripts": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "@symfony-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@symfony-scripts"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "public",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": null
},
"minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

1. I am able to clear the cache using both 'php app/console cache:clear' and 'php app/console cache:clear --no-warmup'
2. I am also able to 'rm -rf app/cache/*' and I have changed the permission on the cache folder 'sudo chmod -R 777 app/cache'
3. I am using ansible which sets the date.timezone='America/New_York'

Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Give us **composer.json** file

Comment: Just added the composer.json file

Comment: Are you running `composer install` locally or on the VM too?

Comment: I tried running on both local and VM.  I am getting an error   [Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException]
  Failed to remove directory "/var/www/fisher.dev/app/cache/de~/annotations": .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the issue was with my operating system macOS High Sierra v10.13.1.  Currently there is a bug with this os and vagrant which has to do with Vagrant's file sync, NFS and the mapping of files on the macOS.

More info:
http://www.qed42.com/blog/macos-sierra-issues-vagrant

Answer (score 1):

the problem seems to come from how VMs deal with mapped paths.

Change the ownership and permissions on files in the project directory from within the VM would execute without error - but upon further investigation, You could see that the ownership and permissions hadn't actually been changed.

Comment: I tried running "sudo chmod -R 777 app/cache" both locally and on the VM but I am still getting an error where it fails to remove directory in /app/cache/de~/annotations"